# How to redirect_to with status code 200 strictly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4

1. I am maintaining a rails 4 application.
2. In it the front end is designed using angular so all the html pages are present in public folder and obviously lot of redirect_to in the application.
3. But the issue is that when ever the rails application do a redirect to it send the status code as 302 but the requirement is status code should be 200 ok only.
4. Is their a way in rails to strictly send the status code to 200 ok always on all redirect_to.
   format.html { redirect_to root_path + '#/menu' }

now,How to redirect_to using status code 200 ok

Answer (score 0):

> How to redirect_to using status code 200 ok

You cannot!

From the [*doc*](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Redirecting.html)

> The status code must be a 3xx HTTP code, or redirection will not
>   occur.

That said, although there is an option to send custom status code with `redirect_to`, you **cannot** send *200* as a status code.